# Movie where holding their breath makes people invisible

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching an English language (probably live-action) film as a kid (on the TV, but I don't think it was a series) about which I remember the part where there was a group of people who could turn invisible when they held their breath and, at one point, they are almost given away while hiding when one (possibly a child) can't hold thier breath long enough.  They were possibly aliens.  This would have been early 80s, I think, but possibly an older movie being reshown.  What movie was it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Earthbound (1981)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthbound_%281981_film%29) [[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082308/)]

Based on the holding-one's-breath-to-turn-invisible plot device, the time-period, and the match of many other descriptions you gave, I'm guessing this is the film you are looking for.

In the comments for this video, someone posted:

> "Thank you for uploading this. I must have seen it when it aired on NBC in '82, because I remember the "holding your breath to turn invisible" thing, and particularly the scene shown briefly at 3:04. It's been bugging me for decades, wondering what this movie was. Now I know. :D"

Comment: This is also something that happens in the movie Paul(2011) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1092026/

Comment: It's not Paul, he said it happened when he was a kid.

Comment: Also referenced in Miyazaki's "Spirited Away" to help Chihiro get across the bridge of Spirits.